# How get the toolbar added with 'OnCustomizationEvent' from interface 'ICustomizationFilter'?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.4

I'm implementing the interfaz ICustomizationFilter, and using the event 'OnCustomizationEvent' of this way:

```c#
public sealed partial class eManager : Extension, ICustomizationFilter
{
    public bool OnCustomizationEvent(esriCustomizationEvent custEventType, object comObject)
    {
        Debug.Write("------------> cust event type:" + custEventType);

        if (custEventType == esriCustomizationEvent.esriCEInvokeCommand)
        {
            if (comObject.ToString() != "Toolbar")
            {
                if (comObject as ICommandItem != null)
                {
                    ICommandItem loButton = (ICommandItem)comObject;
                    MessageBox.Show("button: " + loButton.Name);
                }
                else if (comObject as ICommandBar != null)
                {
                    ICommandBar loToolbar = (ICommandBar)comObject;
                    MessageBox.Show("bar: " + loToolbar.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error casting comObject");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I need get the id or name of toolbar added.
The event is firing, but I can't cast the comObject when it's a toolbar. It Only 
cast when a button fires the event.

How can I get the toolbar's data when it fires the event?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, in that I have not use this method for toolbars but for esris commands (buttons). 
Each ESRI command and toolbar has a unique name and UID
Rather than trying to use the comObject,  find the command name and PUID
I am using the ICustomizationfilter to intercept a user click. Along the way I can get the command_name and UID. In VB.Net

```
If custEventType = ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriCustomizationEvent.esriCEInvokeCommand Then
  ' My reading is that esriCEInvokeCommand always has eventCtx as a command item
  If TypeOf eventCtx Is ICommandItem Then    
    Dim pCommandItem As ICommandItem
    Dim CommandName As String
    Dim pUID As UID

    ' get the command item, its name and UID
    pCommandItem = TryCast(eventCtx, ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem)
    ' test for nothing if you want
    CommandName = pCommandItem.Name
    pUID = pCommandItem.ID
```

Also check out the use of the ICommandBars interface with the find method. 
This is an old link but may give you a start. 
[ICommandBars Interface](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjectsonline/componenthelp/esriCore/ICommandBars.htm)